# msiexec Powershell silent install

Tags: powershell, if-statement, windows-installer, silent-installer

I am searching for a Powershell Script which allows me to silent install a msi file.
We have over 25000 PCs so i have to do that with a script.

Unfortunately at the moment a window popping up (Windows Installer) after the execution which shows the parameter of a msi file. Nothing more, no other "error messages" are popping up.

The first thing the Script should do is to check if the PC is a Desktop or Mobile Device.
If its a Desktop device he should write in a file "Desktop Configuration was used".
In the same time the msi installer should start with some parameter.
If its a Laptop the procedure should be nearly the same.

After the installation is successful the user should be signed out.

I need this script to implement 2FA in our company.

The code at the moment looks like this:

```
IF ( ((Get-ComputerInfo | select -expand CsPCSystemType) -LIKE "Desktop") )
    {
        Write-Output "Desktop Configuration was used." >> \\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\Log\$env:Computername.txt 
        
        
        msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0setup.msi" /passive /norestart /L*v "%~dp0setup.log"

    }    

ELSE {
        Write-Output "Laptop Configuration was used." >> \\XXX.XXX.XX\X\XX\XXX\XXXX\$env:Computername.txt 
        msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0setup.msi" /passive /norestart  /L*v "%~dp0setup.log"

    }   

Write-Output "Lock Configuration was used." >> \\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\Log\$env:Computername.txt
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: _Unfortunately at the moment i got errors that the msi file couldnt be installed._ Perhaps update the question with the exact errors?

Comment: Done :) Im very sorry that i didnt do this at the beginning. It shows a window (Windows Installer) with all the msiexec parameters. No other error messages.

Comment: When calling an executable with parameters via PowerShell, I would normally pass the parameters as an array, although I'm not sure if this will fix the issue you are facing. Instead of `msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0setup.msi" /passive /norestart /L*v "%~dp0setup.log"` try `$parameters = "/i", "%~dp0setup.msi","/passive","/norestart","/L*v", "%~dp0setup.log"` and then call msiexec like this `&msiexec.exe $parameters`.

Comment: What does the log file contain? That might tell you what commandline arguments it doesn't like - for example maybe the msi file is missing or unavailable (I think ```%~dp0``` is interpreted by the *Command Prompt*, so it might be trying to look for a file called literally ```%~dp0setup.msi``` rather than expanding the tokens. Also, if it's the exact same ```msiexec``` command for laptop and desktop you don't need to duplicate it in both branches of the ```if``` - just put it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token `%~dp0` (which resolves to the directory where the current script resides in) only works in batch scripts.

In PowerShell, replace `$~dp0` by `$PSScriptRoot`. That should solve the problem of msiexec showing up with the available command-line options.

Another problem of your script is that `msiexec` runs asynchronously, when called directly as a command. So your script will be finished while the installation is still running, which is propably not what you want. This is caused by `msiexec.exe` being a GUI application. To run GUI applications synchronously, use `Start-Process -Wait`.

```sh
$Arguments = "/i", "`"$PSScriptRoot\setup.msi`"", "/passive", "/norestart", "/L*v", "`"$PSScriptRoot\setup.log`""
$msiProcess = Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList $Arguments -PassThru

# Check if installation was successful 
# 0 = ERROR_SUCCESS, 3010 = ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED
if( $msiProcess.ExitCode -in 0, 3010 ) {
    Write-Host "Installation succeeded with exit code $($msiProcess.ExitCode)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooo much, that is the solution <3

Answer (score 0):

Try passing silent switches (/qn! or /qb!) instead of /passive flag.